# How to enable landscape mode in a single ViewController in NavigationController hierarchy

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have 3 `UIViewControllers` in `UINavigationController` hierarchy.

How do I enable landscape mode only for the last one of them? (or block landscape in 1st and 2nd).

(I open each of them by pushing 1st > 2nd > 3rd )

I tried overriding UINavigationController with those methods:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    UIViewController *top = self.topViewController;

    if ([top isMemberOfClass:[PictureViewController class]]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
    } else {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
    }
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    UIViewController *top = (UIViewController*) self.topViewController;

    if ([top isMemberOfClass:[PictureViewController class]]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

`PictureViewController` is 3rd `UIViewController`. `shouldAutorotate` returns `YES` for it and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` returns `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;`

but landscape is not enabled.

Comment: You can do it by using category for UINavigationController class or custom UINavigationController class which will listen to orientation changes and depending on your condition you can enable it.

Comment: I edited my question with some code, isn't that what I did?

Comment: Check if all the orientations are enabled in summary in project target  or you check it in your .plist file in supported files folder of your project.

Comment: I checked that. All besides upside down portrait are enabled.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this check

```
if ([top isMemberOfClass:[PictureViewController class]]) {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
} else {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

is correct working?

Try override methods -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate and -(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations in your view controllers and in Navigation controller only invoke this methods.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
   return [self.topViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
 }

 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
     return [self.topViewController shouldAutorotate];
 }
```

And as noticed user  Pavan Saberjack, check supported orientations in project plist.